# Heroku Push rejected: fails when building dependencies if Grunt is one of them - "(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected..."

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, gruntjs

I'm quite puzzled since I pushed to Heroku with no problem twice today before it started rejecting any `git push` attempt. (I added comments to the log below.)

```
//Everything is smooth and then...
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral. 
remote:        (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.     
remote:        (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.     
remote:        (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
//hundreds of that line above again and again...
// Then this line below ONCE
remote:        npm(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral. 
//Then hundreds of that other line again...
remote:        (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.     
remote:        (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
//And eventually...
remote:        
remote:        util.js:35
remote:        var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, function(x) {
remote:        ^
remote:        RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to nameOfProject.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/nameOfProject.git
 ! [remote rejected]     master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nameOfProject.git'
```

Locally, I can `npm rebuild` with no problem and run the app too.

None of my util.js file has `var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, funct...` anywhere, in fact, I can't find that line of code.

From what I read in other questions, the "`(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.`" could be related to Grunt, but I didn't touch my Gruntfile.js for days if not weeks so <del>I doubt that would be the issue.</del>

**EDIT**
Turns out that Grunt IS causing the problem. If we take every Grunt related dependency out of our package.json file, we can push to Heroku.
So my guess is that Grunt updated something, that thing is out of our control and it somehow doesn't work wit Heroku.

For now, our solution is to not push Grunt to heroku since we don't need it there anyway. But it would be great to understand what's going on. If you experience the same issue or have a better understanding please share!

Here is our package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ourName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/maps": "^0.3.1",
    "angular-i18n": "1.6.6",
    "angular-touch": "1.6.6",
    "async": "0.2.8",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "bwip": "~0.6.3",
    "cloudinary": "1.0.1",
    "connect-flash": "0.1.0",
    "connect-mongodb": "1.1.4",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "cron": "1.0.1",
    "ejs": "0.8.4",
    "express": "3.2.5",
    "express-subdomain": "1.0.5",
    "feed-read": "0.0.1",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^0.10.0",
    "googleapis": "^17.1.0",
    "http-auth": "1.2.2",
    "ipware": "^1.0.0",
    "jade": "~0.27.4",
    "js2xml": "0.0.6",
    "jsonify": "0.0.0",
    "lame": "1.2.1",
    "mailchecker": "3.0.27",
    "mailchimp": "*",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "1.7.0",
    "moment": "2.1.0",
    "mongodb": "1.3.10",
    "mongoose": "3.6.13",
    "netmask": "^1.0.6",
    "newrelic": "~1.3.1",
    "node-schedule": "1.2.3",
    "nodemailer": "2.4.2",
    "nodetime": ">=0.8.4",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "octobat-npm": "^2.0.1",
    "optimist": "0.3.4",
    "password-generator": "2.1.0",
    "pdfkit": "~0.2.7",
    "request": "2.81.0",
    "rollbar": "2.0.0",
    "stripe": "4.24.0",
    "temp": "~0.6.0",
    "time": "0.8.0",
    "timekit": "*",
    "touch": "^3.1.0",
    "twilio": "^2.11.1",
    "uglify-js": "1.3.3",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "v8tools": "*",
    "wav": "0.1.2",
    "when": "1.7.1",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-momentjs": "^0.2.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "chai": "*",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "database-cleaner": "0.7.0",
    "expect.js": "*",
    "factory-lady": "0.1.0",
    "grunt": ">=0.4.1",                 //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",   //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1", //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",   //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.0.1",   //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "grunt-hash": "^0.5.0",             //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",          //REMOVED AND THEN IT WORKS
    "lodash": "1.2.x",
    "mocha": "1.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.1.0",
    "pixrem": "^3.0.2",
    "vows": ">=0.6.4",
    "zombie": "2.0.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "3.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test vows test/api/*.js test/web/*.js --spec",
    "start": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: can you update your question and post your `package.json` too

Comment: Thanks @antzshrek, I updated the question as we now know that Grunt clearly is the dependency causing problem. (Which is a step forward, yay!)

Comment: Do you have any `util.js` in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem might be coming from this very lines I comment at the ending of your `package.json`

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x", //here
    "npm": "3.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test vows test/api/*.js test/web/*.js --spec",
    "start": "" //here
  }
}
```

On the `engines` your version of `node` can result to that error, so I suggest you change your `engines` to this below:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "*", //this should make your app run on the most recent version of node
  "npm": "*" //this should make your app run on the most recent version of npm
```

Then is your `scripts`, you still didn't specify your entry point from your `start`. Your `scripts` should be something like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test vows test/api/*.js test/web/*.js --spec",
    "start": "node index.js" //this is where you should place your entry point.
  }
```

**Note**: It is not a most to use `index.js`, you can write your entry point to the app with the name you called it, maybe `app.js` or `server.js` or whatever your called it.

And I also notice you didn't have a `"main": ""` in your `package.json`.

Implement these corrections to your `package.json` and your problem should be fixed